# Why does Cygwin not start Bash as a login shell

Tags: bash, cygwin, .profile

Apparently, when I start cygwin, bash is not invoked as a login shell with the consequence that my `~/.profile` is not read.

I am not sure if this by design or if I have goofed with some setting somewhere.

Is there a canonical way to start cygwin's bash in a way that it executed my `~/.profile`?

**How I am starting cygwin**: I go to the start button and click the Icon named *Cygwin Terminal*. It's properties show as target `C:\tools\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`

Comment: Try setting BASH_ENV variable to point your profile file

Comment: How are you starting bash?

Comment: @varro I have edited the question

Comment: Hmm... that's strange - that final dash is supposed invoke a login shell according to `man mintty`.  A few things to check:  do you have *both* a ~/.profile *and* a ~/.bash_profile?  What's in your ~/.[bash_]profile?  My ~/.profile essentially just sources ~/.bashrc, and I put all my settings there.

Answer (score 2):

The default shell for mintty is specified in `/etc/passwd`. If it does not exist, do the following:

Run mintty.exe as administrator and enter: `mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`

This will create your log in credentials and should fix the issue. Leave the shortcut target as it is assuming the bin path you have stated is correct.

For more information: [Cygwin mkpasswd documentation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html#:~:text=The%20mkpasswd%20program%20can%20be,disconnected%20from%20its%20domain%20controller.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jiwopene! Going forward, I will format links as suggested.